# What exactly does this error, "tar: Failed to set default locale" means?

Tags: r

I am a COMPLETE Newbie for this community and coding as well.

I wonder what exactly this error message is telling me!

`tar: Failed to set default locale`

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not well suited for this platform. Pls. refer to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section on how to ask questions here and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is your OS, linux? `tar` is a system command that compresses/decompresses files, it stands for *tape archive*. This question shouldn't be tagged R, it should be tagged `<your OS>`. Please post the command you ran to get the error.